# Running cumulative count group by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have an table with values like this:

```
 count     month-year
    6         12-2020
    5         12-2020
    4         11-2020
    3         11-2020
    3         10-2020
    2         10-2020
    2         09-2020
    1         09-2020
```

I want to group the data by the month and show the sum of the count for the current month and the months before it. I am expecting the following output:

```
count     month-year
26        12-2020      <- month 12 count equal to month 12 sum + count start from month 9
15        11-2020      <- month 11 count equal to month 11 sum + count start from month 9
8         10-2020      <- month 10 count equal to month 9 sum + month 10
3         09-2020      <- assume month 9 is the launch month, count = sum count of month 9
```

Comment: By the way, you should store `month-year` as a date, use `EOMONTH` or `DATEFROMPARTS` to get a single date in each month

Comment: You are asking for a running total by month, It would help if you included your syntax that you have attempted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `SUM` here twice, both as an aggregate and as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT
    [month-year],
    SUM(SUM(count)) OVER (ORDER BY [month-year]) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    [month-year]
ORDER BY
    [month-year] DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to calculate the desired result

```
select Distinct [month-year] , 
SUM(count) OVER (ORDER BY [month-year]) AS count
from yourTable
order by [month-year] desc
```